# how to dump android UI component actions and its data to help to solve the hard-to-reproducible bugs

Tags: android, automation

Is there any way to record user actions in android. Like if someone clicks a button or enters a text, or scrolls a list, how to identify those actions and record the data from the UI component ?

Let me give more background of my intention. Sometimes during my manual testing, there are some so called hard to reproducible bugs. Sometimes it's hard for me to remember what I have done before the bug happens especially after a quite long time. So one of my idea is to record what I have done before the bug appears. I'd like to use a light way, not recording the screens, so maybe we can simply dump user actions and the corresponding UI controls' data which can give us some clues to reminder me what i have done and what data has been outputted to save the circumstances.
Is there any better way to solve the hard-to-reproducible bugs?

Answer (score 3):

Yep, **adb** supports it natively since API 16 (Android JellyBean 4.1) with [UI-Automator](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html).

`adb shell uiautomator events`

Bam, that's it. Tells you the views clicked and their text/description from the perspective of the Accessibility framework.

Comment: This is not a recorder, which is what the OP is requesting.

Comment: @CommonsWare, what do you mean OP?

Comment: @bettermanlu: Sorry, "OP" = original poster, used in discussion boards to refer to the person who started the discussion thread. In StackOverflow, "OP" usually refers to the person who wrote the question, and it does in this case, meaning it refers to you. While **`adb shell uiautomator events`** does dump accessibility events to the console (except on my x86 emulator for some reason), I would not call it a "recorder", as you cannot play back the results, nor can you "record the data from the UI component".

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare. For me it's ok to only dump the accessing events, but I also want to dump the data from the UI component, such as all the data in a list view.

Comment: @bettermanlu: You have to write your own JUnit or uiautomator tests for that. **`adb shell uiautomator events`** certainly does not do that.

Answer (score 1):

Testdroid tool has Recorder that allows recording user actions and generating UI automation tests. http://testdroid.com/product/testdroid-recorder#0